# How install libgd undre macOS Catalina without brew?

Tags: installation, macos-catalina

I need the gd.h header file, and possibly others, from libgd. How should that be installed under macOS Catalina *without* using homebrew?

(I should not use brew because I'm using MacPorts for many things.)

Answer (score 0):

libgd can be installed from MacPorts by running the following:

```
sudo port install gd2
```

[Summary Page](https://ports.macports.org/port/gd2/summary)

Comment: Unfortunately, still the WIMS server I'm trying to install failed to find the header file gd.h.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/a/3299377/10763533 help?